# Multiple matrix multiplication

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

In numpy, I have an array of N 3x3 matrices. This would be an example of how I'm storing them (I'm abstracting away the contents):

```
N = 10
matrices = np.ones((N, 3, 3))
```

I also have an array of 3-vectors, this would be an example:

```
vectors = np.ones((N, 3))
```

I can't seem to figure out how to multiply those via numpy, so as to achieve something like this:

```
result_vectors = []
for matrix, vector in zip(matrices, vectors):
    result_vectors.append(matrix @ vector)
```

with the `result_vector`'s shape (upon casting to array) being `(N, 3)`.
However, a list implementation is out of the question due to speed.

I've tried np.dot with various transpositions, but the end result didn't get the shape right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)  -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',matrices,vectors)
```

Steps :

1) Keep the first axes aligned.

2) Sum-reduce the last axes from the input arrays against each other.

3) Let the remainining axes(second axis from `matrices`) be element-wise multiplied.

Comment: Looks like `matmul` can be used with a bit of dimension massaging: `(matrices @ vectors[:,:,None]).squeeze()`