# Simplified implementation of an equation involving matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to compute the following two matrices P and Q in a succinct form so that instead of looping over all the indices I can compute the matrices in a single shot.

[image]

Can one suggest me what would be an efficient way to compute these matrices P and Q in python? I am attaching the code for my implementation. I want to avoid looping over the indices i and j and instead compute P in a single expression.

```
import numpy as np

def sum_matrices(i,j):
      a=0;
      for m in range(M+1):
            a+= p[m]*W[m][i]*np.dot(A[m][j][:],x);
return a;

for i in range(N):
     for j in range(N):
          P[i][j]=sum_matrices(i,j);
```

Comment: `numpy` supports whole-matrix computations

Comment: You mean computing each element of $P$ by looping over i and j and using the above formula?

Comment: Please show your current implementation that you'd like to improve, I'd imagine I'd have an easier time understanding what you need to do seeing it in code then in math.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Did it.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Why is it downvoted and put on hold? I added the code and explained my approach and the issue.

Comment: I have no way of knowing who did the downvote (wasn't me) but it was probably before the edit and I'm sorry I didn't retract my close vote in time but I'm still a bit unclear what you are trying to do, where does the `Q`, `P` and `A` matrix come from?

Answer (score 2):

So in `numpy` terms

```
W - (M,N) shape, dtype float
A - (M,N,N)
x - (N,)
p - (M,)
```

Translating your equations, on the fly, to einstein notation, and then to `np.einsum`, I think you want:

```
Ax = np.einsum('mjk,k->mj', A, x)    # sums on k
P = np.einsum('m,mi,mj->ij', p, W, Ax)   # sums on m
pW = np.einsum('m,mi->i', p, W)      # sums on m
Q = np.einsum('m,i,mj->ij', p, pW, Ax)   # sums on m
```

Obviously it needs to be tested with small M and N and sample arrays. I also didn't try to understand the equations in depth; I focused mainly on the indexing notation.

===============

I'd rework you code as:

```
def sum_matrices(i,j):
      a=0;
      for m in range(M):
            a+= p[m]*W[m, i]*np.dot(A[m,j],x);
      return a;

def sum_matrices(i, j):
      Ax = np.array([np.dot(A[m,j,:], x) for m in range(M)])
      a = p * W[:, i] * Ax
      return a.sum()
```

See also [Multiple matrix multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579458/multiple-matrix-multiplication)

Comment: Is there anyway the for loop for i and j can be eliminated? I have to compute these matrices P and Q for a lot of times. So I feel running two for loops would be very slow.

Comment: The `einsum` forms don't loop.

Comment: My bad. So effectively the above answer is 3 different solutions to the same problem right? Two of them involving loops and the einsum one not involving any. Is einsum typically slow or fast compared to above loops approach?

Comment: The `einsum` expression is my primary answer.  The rest are incomplete attempts to improve on your code.